# How to use ui-select2?

Tags: angularjs

```
<select class="input-large" data-ng-model="dldata.adhocPayout.IsPretax" 
             ui-select2 required>
         <option value=""></option>
         <option data-ng-repeat="t in dldata.taxtype"></option>
</select>
```

The upper code is showing a combo-box while downward code displays a textarea(text field):

```
<textarea class="noResize" type="text" 
data-ng-model="dldata.adhocPayout.Description" required></textarea>
```

While I am using `ui-select2` if I click on the reset button the value in textbox resets while the value in combo-box remains as it is. And if I do not use `ui-select2` than both the values get reset. How can I reset the combo-box value using `ui-select2`?